# PHP merge array on nulls

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 * `array` and I want to `merge` them, but each of theme have some `NULL` `rows`.

```
$a = array(
    'a' => NULL,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1
);

$b = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => NULL,
    'c' => 1    
);
```

So, code:

```
$c = array_merge($a,$b);
```

Will give $c:

```
array {
  'a'=> 1
  'b'=> NULL
  'c'=>1
}
```

Is there build in or simple way to do margin `($a,$b)` like following, but now `$a` is overwritten for every same index from `$b`. I want `$b` to be overwritten by $a index if `$b` index is `null` - in example `$b['b']` should be overwritten from `$a`

All NULL rows should be filled if possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can use [**`array_filter`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to remove null values in both array and then merge them

```
$a = array(
    'a' => NULL,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1
);

$b = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => NULL,
    'c' => 1    
);

$b  = array_filter($b);
$a  = array_filter($a);
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

This will output

```
array(3) {
  ["b"]=> int(1)
  ["c"]=> int(1)
  ["a"]=> int(1)
}
```

[**LIVE SAMPLE**](http://ideone.com/IE7PO0)

As side note i would add that using `array_filter` without second parameter will end up in deleting all `NULL` values as well as `EMPTY` array etc. If you want to only remove `NULL` values so you will need to use `array_filter($yourarray, 'strlen');`

**EDITED**

If you want to preserve `NULL` if both arrays have it with the same key and supposing that both arrays have same number of keys/values, then you will need to loop inside your array and build a new array preserving `NULL` where you need

```
$a = array(
    'a' => NULL,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1,
    'd' => NULL
);

$b = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => NULL,
    'c' => 1,   
    'd' => NULL,
);

$c = array();
foreach($a as $key => $val)
{
    if($key == NULL && $b[$key] == NULL)
    {
        $c[$key] = $val;
    } else if($key != NULL && $b[$key] == NULL) {
        $c[$key]= $val;
    } else if($key != NULL && $b[$key] != NULL) {
        $c[$key]= $b[$key];
    } else {
        $c[$key]= $b[$key];
    }
}
var_dump($c);
```

This will output

```
array (size=4)
  'a' => int 1
  'b' => int 1
  'c' => int 1
  'd' => NULL
```

[**LIVE SAMPLE**](http://ideone.com/oxIe2q)

Comment: What if there will be 'd' index null on only 1 of arrays. I mean overwrtie 'nulls' if possible, if not they should stay. In this case ALL nulls will be removed.

Comment: @Kluska000 i've updated my answer fitting your request, please check it

Comment: basing on your solution I've tried this - seems to be working and more simple http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rqz-sd4

Comment: @Kluska000 this is nice if it does what you need, i'm glad i helped you. If you feel answer was correct then don't forget to accept it to help people in the future with similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with a simple one liner like this:

```
$c = array_filter($b) + array_filter($a) + array_fill_keys(array_keys($b),null);
```

This would preserve all keys and values of `$b` except where falsey in which case they will be either replaced with values from `$a` or as a last resort replaced with `null`.

When merging arrays with the `+` operator the order in which they appear from left to right equates to the precedence.  So the leftmost position will hold it's value unless the key does not exist.

You can also reverse the order and use `array_merge()`, but for me it's harder on the eyes:

```
$c = array_merge(array_fill_keys(array_keys($b),null) + array_filter($a) + array_filter($b));
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers address merging **two arrays that may have different keys**, which is what lead me to this SO post. It happens to actually be pretty straight forward fortunately:

```
function arrayMergeIfNotNull($arr1, $arr2) {
    foreach($arr2 as $key => $val) {
        $is_set_and_not_null = isset($arr1[$key]);
        if ( $val == NULL && $is_set_and_not_null ) {
            $arr2[$key] = $arr1[$key];
        }
    }
    return array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

Now, merging these two arrays:

```
$a = array('a' => NULL, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 1, 'd' => NULL, 'z' => 'zebra');
$b = array('a' => 1, 'b' => NULL, 'c' => 1, 'd' => NULL, 'f' => 'frank');
```

with:

```
var_dump(arrayMergeIfNotNull($a, $b));
```

will produce:

```
array (size=6)
  'a' => int 1
  'b' => int 1
  'c' => int 1
  'd' => NULL
  'z' => 'zebra'
  'f' => 'frank'
```

Note this answer **also** solves the problem of two arrays with the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

then you have to pass $b as the first parameter

$c = array_merge($b,$a);

you can use this function

```
function mergeArray($array1, $array2)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value)
    {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }

    foreach ($array2 as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (!isset($result[$key] || $result[$key] == null)
        {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: In this case not null row of $b will be overwritten by null row from $a. All NULL rows should be filled if possible.

Comment: function mergeArray($array1, $array2)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value)
    {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }

    foreach ($array2 as $key=>$value)
    {
        if ($result[$key] == null)
        {
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve keys that have a value of NULL in **both** arrays, you can use a custom function that ignores those entries from the second array if (and only if) there is a corresponding non-NULL entry in the first array. It would look like this:

```
function arrayMergeIgnoringNull($arr1, $arr2) {
    $new2 = array();
    forEach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
        if (($value !== NULL) || !isSet($arr1[$key])) {
           $new2[$key] = $value;
        } 
    }
    return array_merge($arr1, $new2);
}
$c = arrayMergeIgnoringNull($a, $b);
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/an6bH9)**.